# php get from mysql all values by column to json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I must put to json_encode all values of specifed mysql table column

```
$fromdate       = $_GET['fromdate'];
$getrezhiredh = safe_query("
    SELECT rezhour FROM rezhiredhours 
    WHERE rezdate = '".$fromdate."' ORDER BY rezhour
");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($getrezhiredh)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

print json_encode($rows);
```

With code above i have one problem. This code return result only when in table we have one row with selected data. In this case json_encode() result is

[{"rezhour":"1"}]

But when table have more than one row with selected data result don't return anything but

```
[]
```

How put to json_encode() all values selected from table?

---

**EDIT:**

I just wonder why in case when we have more rows in table with selected data, result don't give as example below

[{"rezhour": { [0] => "1",[1] => "4" }]

Instead in result we have "[]"

---

Thank You in advance.

Comment: That's weird, it should work. Try `var_dump($rows)` and see what it actually contains when there are more than one row.

Comment: Thank You for your comment.

Still wrong. var_dump($rows) give correct result only when we have one row with data, otherwise return array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($getrezhiredh)
```

to

```
mysql_fetch_object($getrezhiredh)
```

Comment: I got same result as above. [] when we have more than one row with data

Comment: remove $rows = array();

Comment: php error - "Undefined variable: rows in (...) on line X"

Comment: your using msql_fetch_assoc, this is deprecated. You have to use msqli. could you add more code to see how you create your connection?

Comment: your db values would also help

Comment: 'mysql' is deprecated from php 5.5 as i know... i use older php version... and but the way mysqli is not an option ... the question is json_encode() allows put all selected values of one mysql table column... i need roughly  result {"rezhour": { [0] => "1", [1] => "4" }; 1 and 4 are the each selected row values of one column 'rezhour' - and one more thing... my table have no PRIMARY column and don't use AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 0):

Results from [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) are different than you think. Each row is more or less like this:

```
array(1)
    "rezhour" => "1"
```

So you access the data it like this:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($getrezhiredh)) {
    $rows[] = $r["rezhour"];
}
```